# kafka-console-producer : command not found

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

After connecting to the EC2 instance and downloading Kafka and Java, I ran the following commands:

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx256M -Xms128M"
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh -daemon config/zookeeper-properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-properties
```

then I try to run the command:

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list IP:9092 --topic mytopic
```

and it says

> command not found

Comment: Is there a specific reason against using MSK or other managed Kafka instance?

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with Kafka itself. Your Kafka `bin` directory, where all the scripts such as `kafka-console-producer` are stored, is not included in the PATH variable which means that there is no way for your OS to find these scripts without you specifying their exact location.

You can modify your PATH variable such that it includes the Kafka `bin` folder. Run this command:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/path-to-bin-dir/bin"
```

This will not persist through reboots though so you should include this statement in one of your startup files such as `~/.bashrc`.

Another option is to simply run the command by specifying the absolute path to it, starting at the root of your filesystem.

```
/path-to-bin-dir/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list IP:9092 --topic mytopic
```

Or you can simply `cd` into the `bin` folder and run it from there.

```
./kafka-console-producer --broker-list IP:9092 --topic mytopic
```

Comment: I tried using the above.... first thing sir there is no .bashrc file present there to add path... and i tried other methods also .... the answer is no such file or directory

Comment: `~/.bashrc` doesn't need to be present on some installations. Go into your home directory and execute `ls -lA` to see whether it exists or not. If not, then you can create it but you should consult manual for your particular OS to see what startup files are being used. If you `cd` into kafka `bin` folder and the last option that I have mentioned is giving your this error then it means that the file doesn't exist and your installation is possibly broken. List files in that directory to be sure that the mentioned `kafka-console-producer` file exists.

Comment: To execute in a docker container, try running this command: 
docker exec --interactive --tty broker \
kafka-console-producer --broker-list IP:9092 --topic mytopic

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

use this command :

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

kafka-server-start.sh is inside bin folder and needs server.properties as an arg which is inside config folder. So the prefixes bin/ and config/.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead from the Kafka installation directory

```
bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list IP:9092 --topic mytopic
```

Note the `bin/` at the beginning of the command.

Comment: I tried but it still isn't working out .... it is showing no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list IP:9092 --topic mytopic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).